# Getting error 0x800f081f when trying to Windows-Update 22H2 to 23H2

Tags: windows-11, windows-update

I'm trying to run Windows Update on a machine with Windows 11 23H2. The download succeeds, but after hitting 47% completion of the installation process, I get an error:

```
Windows 11, version 23H2
Install error - 0x800f081f
```

I tried following instructions regarding how to handle this error. Specifically, I used:

- `sfc /scannow`
- `chkdsk` with relevant switches
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

with restarts between them. This had no effect.

How can I install the Windows updates relevant to my system?

---

More system info:

- Windows 11 Pro
- Version 22H2
- OS build 22621.2283
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22662.1000.0

X86_64 version on an AMD Ryzen CPU.

Comment: One of the only reasons for 0x800f081f is a corrupt component store. You can’t use a corrupt component store to repair system files that might be corrupt. My suggestion download a Windows 11 22H2 ISO, perform an in-place repair of your system files, then and only then upgrade to 23H2. Outside of that Windows Update logs would e required for additional diagnostic

Comment: @John: He's doing just the opposite.

Comment: @einpoklum - If you are going to pull this "Microsoft hates its users" line, then I refuse to help you.  Your current issue is not Microsoft's fault. "Don't they keep an update/installation log somewhere?" - **That log exists which is the reason I asked for it.**

Comment: @Ramhound: 1. Did you downvote the question because you dislike my comment? 2. Rephrasing.

Comment: @Ramhound: Is there any way to check whether my "component store" is corrupt? Also, where are the update logs? Microsoft seems to hate users enough to not want to tell us where the log is in which the problem with the update is actually listed.

Comment: @einpoklum - No, I didn't downvote because of your inappropriate comment.  I issued a downvote because I asked for the logs from Windows Update, and instead of providing them, you submitted a comment that didn't contribute much. Microsoft has documented how to generate [Windows Update logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs). I will also need the logs from the attempt to upgrade the system to better understand the reason it failed. [Setup Diag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag)

Comment: @Ramhound: Ah, ok, now I get it. So, the thing is, I'm only around that computer once every several days. I'll get those logs next time I'm there.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Update fails, you may force the issue by downloading
the ISO and doing
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).
I would in any case advise to execute the third point below
for clearing `SoftwareDistribution` before doing that.

In case you run into problems and require absolutely to fix
Windows Update, I list below all the fixes I know for it:

- Run the Windows Update troubleshooter in:
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters >
  Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*
- Run Microsoft's [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows 10](//support.microsoft.com/help/4027322)
- Reset Windows Update components by running these commands in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  net stop wuauserv
  net stop cryptSvc
  net stop bits
  net stop msiserver
  Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
  Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
  net start msiserver
  net start wuauserv
  net start cryptSvc
  net start bits
  ```

  If all goes well, delete the `.old` folders (or return them if a problem
  arrives).
- Run the DISM tool in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
  ```
- Run the following in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  SC config trustedinstaller start= auto
  ```

Comment: 1. Download a 22H2 ISO, or a 23H2 ISO? 2. I tried the troubleshooter, it noticed there's trouble, and that's about it. 3. Should I try the steps in the second part of your answer before, after, or only instead of using the ISO?

Comment: The third point you should do. If this doesn't help, do the 23H2 upgrade via its ISO. If it fails, try first the 22H2 ISO. Just to note that if all that fails, then the problem is more serious.

Comment: @einpoklum - You need a 22H2 ISO to fix your system corruption and a 23H2 iso to upgrade to 23H2 after you fix the system corruption

Comment: @Ramhound: That might be the case, but this entails downloading two large files, so I counsel trying it in stages.

Comment: @harrymc - Windows ISO is hardly a large file in 2024.  Updates to console games are 10x larger which are released monthly. I also suggest performing the repair and upgrade in stages. The author wanted to know which ISO to download so I recommend they download them both.

Comment: **I caution that these steps, will wipe all information, necessary to diagnose the problem.**